# ASP.NET SMTP + web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, smtp

Im working on a legacy app that has this logic in its code that I cant modify unfortunately. I have the proper settings in the web.config and was wondering if i list the proper SMTP server would the web.config settings take care of the credentials?

If not what options do i have for sending email out with this code?

```
  string str13 = "";
    str13 = StringType.FromObject(HttpContext.Current.Application["MailServer"]);
    if (str13.Length > 2)
    {
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = str13;
    }
    else
    {
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
    }
    SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

Comment: I used Reflector to look at the source.

Comment: I would look into System.Net.Mail instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.Mail` does not expose any settings for specifying credentials, unfortunately. It *is* possible to send authenticated emails, though, because `System.Web.Mail` is built on top of CDOSYS. [Here's a KB article which describes how to do it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555287), but you basically have to modify some properties on the message itself:

```
var msg = new MailMessage();
if (userName.Length > 0)
{
    string ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/";
    msg.Fields.Add(ns + "smtpserver", smtpServer);
    msg.Fields.Add(ns + "smtpserverport", 25) ;
    msg.Fields.Add(ns + "sendusing", cdoSendUsingPort) ;
    msg.Fields.Add(ns + "smtpauthenticate", cdoBasic); 
    msg.Fields.Add(ns + "sendusername", userName); 
    msg.Fields.Add(ns + "sendpassword", password); 
}
msg.To = "someone@domain.com"; 
msg.From = "me@domain.com";
msg.Subject = "Subject";
msg.Body = "Message";
SmtpMail.Send(msg);
```

Whether that works for your situation or not, I'm not sure....

Comment: can it use the SMTP settings from the web.config? Im not clear on when thoose vlaues get picked up and when they might get ignored.

Comment: No, `System.Web.Mail` does not support any settings from the web.config file (only `System.Net.Mail` does). The settings I've given need to be specified on *every* message.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for. Shoot..ok...time to try and dig up the source code. Thanks for the info!

Comment: No probs. If you're going to have to modify the code, I'd suggest switching to `System.Net.Mail` anyway. The API is similar, but at least then you can configure the authentication in the web.config.